# How to center a grid while having it display as many items as possible within the parent element?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Looking to center a grid with 8 elements within a parent div that is a flex item. I want to be able to:

1. Center the Grid within the parent element while displaying as many columns as the parent width allows
2. Have the grid wrap any elements onto the next row if they don't fit within the parent container's constraints.
3. Have all elements within the grid the same height

But for some reason the grid only displays 2 columns per row

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
<div class="item">Item 1 <br/> test <br/> test</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
<div class="item">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *But for some reason the grid only displays 2 columns per row* --> you defined 2 columns

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah I see what you mea with the `auto auto` I didn't realize that defines 2 columns.  But then I don't know how to have columns defined automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}    
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;  
}    
.item {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The item has a height in your answer. I can't determine the height for my needs  but they need to be equal

Comment: Hi @zer0 , I have edited the code. Use grid-auto-rows: 1fr. It will apply the longest column's height to all the columns.